# Google Sheet, Formula to leave cell blank, or fill based on value of another cell in another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a budget proposal sheet. Two separate tabs, 'Working Calc' and 'Prop #1)

What formula can I use to make the cell on Prop #1 check if Cell on Working Calc is empty, and, if empty, clear contents to make the cell on Prop #1 appear empty. While if not empty, enables existing formula.

The purpose of the formula is that the Prop #1 sheet has a discount line (attached) that is formulated between subtotal and Total Line. But if the 'Working Calc' sheet does not have a value for the discount cell, I want the text for Prop #1 Discount line to disappear rather than saying '$0'

[Tab Set Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf59X.png)

[Working Calc No Discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPAhV.png)
[Prop #1 No Discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0QYI.png)

[Working Calc Discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojhfw.png)
[Prop #1 Discount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4pQN.png)

I have been trying to figure it out using

**=if ('Working Calc'=""**

and

**=('Working Calc'<>**

No combination of tried using any formula I know is getting the desired result. Hoping someone can help

Answer (score -1):

We don't know your exact cell, but suppose it's in P4, then you can add before your current formula:

```
=IF('Working Calc'!P4="","",...put here your formula...)
```

Comment: Bless you sir. So simple lol